# Is “There was not a problem” ok?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

Is “There was not a problem” in common use?

Example:

> I tried to test the device and there was no problem with it.

Comment: It gives the impression that you were expecting to be told off for carrying out the test. I'd put 'I tested the device and it worked perfectly.'

Comment: I would say there wasn't any problem with the test device on my side, would you provide more information how to reproduce the bug ;)

Comment: Are you asking about "not a problem" or "no problem"? The question is not clear.

Comment: I think "there wasn't any problem with the test device" is good for my purpuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird part of your sentence is that you *tried* to test the device. I would expect the sentence to finish by noting there was a problem *with the testing*:

> I tried to test the device but found a problem that prevented me from completing the testing.

The other common difference is that a lot of English speakers say "there is **a** problem" but "there **are no** problems."

If you were indeed successful in testing the device and the device itself had no problems, I would say either of the following:

> I **tested** the device and **found no problems**.
>
> I **tested** the device and there **were no problems**.

Answer (score -2):

"There was not a problem to begin with but I tested the device anyway" is the right usage.The example you stated should be written as "I tested the device and there was no problem with it". Is this the answer you were looking for? This is what I understood from your question.

Comment: I mean that i tested the device and it worked correctly without any problem

Comment: Then you can use "I tested the device and there was no problem in it" or "I tested the device and it worked flawless"

Comment: “There was no problem in it” is not actual English. “There was no problem _with_ it” or, more idiomatically (unless you’re talking about a specific problem), “There were no problems with it” both work, though.

Answer (score -2):

There may have been a confusion. You can be expressing that you manage to test the device by saying so. Although we understand that you are saying that the device is in good condition.